# How to show delivery date i18n +21 day after order creation?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need exactly date_i18n instead of simple date, because it uses translations.
I show the order creation date like that

```
<div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Order Date', 'woocommerce' )?></span> 
<?php 
    if( $date_created = $order->get_date_created() ){
    // Display the localized formatted date
    $formated_date_created = $date_created->date_i18n('j F, Y ');
    echo  $formated_date_created; }  ?>
</div>
```

For delivery date I tried that, it has to be +21 days

```
 <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span><?php echo get_theme_mod('delivery_date_text')?>: </span> 
   <?php 
    // The orders date
    $date_created = $order->get_date_created();
    $date_created =  $date_created->date('j F, Y');
    // The order date + 5 days
    $delivery_date = date_i18n( 'j F, Y', strtotime( $order_date . ' +21 days' ));                       
    echo $delivery_date;?>
 </div>
```

I thought it works fine, but later I saw, that it shows the same deivery date even for older 'orders', that I've made for a test 3-4 days ago. Their delivey date has to be earlier then orders,that I created today.
What's wrong and how to make it work right?

Comment: are you trying to show `21 \ 12 \ 2021 +21 days` or `21 \ 12 \ 2021 + remainig days`

Comment: what is `$order_date` on second snippet? If it is unset, I'd assume `strtotime` will treat it as *today*

Comment: I don't see any assignments for `$order_date` variable in the code. Probably this line `$date_created = $order->get_date_created();` should be changed to this `$order_date = $order->get_date_created();`. `strtotime` show offset for current date unless you specify proper date format. @libertarian

Comment: I try to show 15 December, 2021 in 2 language versions. I've found the snippet with strtotime sommewhere in stackoverflow, in the similar question, a person needed to show +5days in their orders delivery date. I need like that: Order date: 24 November, 2021. Delivery date: 15 December, 2021/  I'll try $order_date = $order->get_date_created(); now, thx

Comment: I think this should be correct  $delivery_date = date_i18n( 'j F, Y', strtotime( $date_created . ' +21 days' )); I really didn't understand at first that I have not $order_date, my mistake